# Using findstr to output to file only if data is found

Tags: windows, command-line

I wanted to use findstr to output the results to a file, but only if the information I am looking for is found.

For instance if I am using this command..

findstr "123456789" input.txt >>results.txt

Then the results.txt file will be a 0KB blank file named results.txt if it can't find
"0123456789".

What I would like is for the results.txt file not to be formed at all if it can't find
"-123456789" in the input.txt file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This effectively only leaves the file if the search term was found:

```
findstr "123456789" input.txt >>results.txt || del results.txt
```

Comment: Stack Overflow aims to provide an answer to one question AIUI.  Open a new question for your followup query.

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /L /c:"prerequisitestring" input.txt >nul 
if not errorlevel 1 findstr /L /c:"targetstring" input.txt >>results.txt
```

should do this in the general case

Comment: Thanks, for this suggestion.  If I then want to do the following, do you have any scripting suggestions to add to the script above?                                                      Folder1 has incoming data, Folder2 is to be used.  When the script sees a new text file in Folder1, copy it to Folder2.  When running the script again if the file in Folder2 is the same as the one in Folder1, then empty Folder2.  When subsequently running the script, keep Folder2 empty until it sees a more recent newer file in Folder1. Then copy the newest file to Folder2 and so on.